# spamassassin attachment scanning

Tags: spamassassin, spam-filter, spam

I have just started using spamassassin for my email server.

I am unable to find an answer for following questions:

1. Does spamassassin scans attachments?
2. If not, what plugins can be used for the same.

As far as I can comprehend spamassassin can dmime an attachment and can scan it if it's in a plain format (like html, txt etc), Is my assumption correct?

Thanks in advance

Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will scan them up to X kilobytes, where X is defined by --max-size parameter given to spamc, or for example the message size limit configured in amavisd-new.

What kind of attachments SpamAssassin will scan is depending on what kind of unarchivers and viewers you have installed. I you don't have (un)zip installed, don't expect SpamAssassin to dig through zip archives ...  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Spamassassin will scan the first X kB of each message-part (where X is configurable).

Comment: Are you sure? If I read the [spamc manpage](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/spamc.txt), I see "--max-size: Set the maximum message size which will be sent to spamd -- any bigger than this threshold and the message will be returned unprocessed". I also recall that spamasssin did not have any way to actually parse message parts, but I also recall that might have changed recently (but I cannot find any reference to this just now...).